# Getting difference of a column between first and last row with count number

Tags: postgresql-10

I have table `mytable` as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE mytable( id, created_at, total_number )
AS VALUES
    ( 17330  , '2018-05-24 19:25:29'::timestamp, 26909 ),
    ( 46331  , '2018-05-25 00:57:34',            26914 ),
    ( 72131  , '2018-05-26 00:48:12',            26944 ),
    ( 102583 , '2018-05-27 00:53:50',            26972 );
```

I would like to get total_number difference between first and the last

I got my first and last row with this query

```
(SELECT * FROM mytable 
    ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 1)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM mytable 
    ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)
```

My query should return this results. How can I achieve it?

```
difference        number_of_rows   avg
(26972-26909=63)  4                63/4
```

Comment: You should divide by 3, not 4 because the column is titled "difference". With 4 values, you get 3 differences. If we have a value every hour (at xx:00), would you divide the diff from midnight to midnight with 25 or 24, to get the hourly average difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another variation. Here the function `first_value` is used to get both the first and last total_number (different directions):

```
select abs(lst - fst) as diff, number_of_rows
     , abs(lst - fst) / number_of_rows as average 
from (
    select count(1) over () as number_of_rows
         , first_value(total_number) over (order by created_at) fst
         , first_value(total_number) over (order by created_at desc) lst
    from tbl
    fetch first 1 rows only
) as t;
```

An alternative is to specify the window frame with `unbounded following` and use the function `last_value`:

```
select abs(lst - fst) as diff, number_of_rows
     , abs(lst - fst) / number_of_rows as average 
from (
    select count(1) over () as number_of_rows
         , first_value(total_number) over (order by created_at) fst
         , last_value(total_number) over (order by created_at 
                                          rows between current row 
                                                and unbounded following
                                         ) lst
    from tbl
    fetch first 1 rows only
) as t;
```

Perhaps it is worth noting that the default window frame is `range between unbounded preceding and current row`, so in the last example, we need to override that to truly see the last row. All rows in the sub-select are identical, so we can pick one randomly (used in both examples).

I believe limit 1 now is part of the standard, but I'm used to `fetch first ...` so I'll stick to that

In this situation, distinct could have been used instead of limit or fetch ...

```
from (
    select distinct count(1) over () as number_of_rows
         , ...
    from tbl
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to get total_number difference between first and the last

My assumption is that there is no faster way to do this if you have a sufficiently large data set and an index on `created_at`

```
SELECT tmax.max - tmin.min AS diff,
  tcount.cnt AS number_of_rows,
  (tmax.max - tmin.min)::double precision / tcount.cnt AS avg
FROM ( SELECT total_number FROM mytable ORDER BY created_at ASC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY ) 
  AS tmin(min)
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT total_number FROM mytable ORDER BY created_at DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY )
  AS tmax(max)
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT count(*) FROM mytable ) AS tcount(cnt);
```

I don't know of a more terse way to tell the planner find the highest and lowest by X, retrieving value Y -- which seems to be what you want.

AFAIK, only this way can the database plan this as one index scan.

Answer (score 0):

Select the `total_number` where `created_at` is the maximum or the minimum, respectively and subtract them to get the `difference`. For `number_of_rows` use `count()`. And `avg` just uses the previously built expressions in the arithmetic expression. It should look something like:

```
SELECT (SELECT mi.total_number
               FROM mytable mi
               WHERE mi.created_at = (SELECT max(mii.created_at)
                                             FROM mytable mii))
       -
       (SELECT mi.total_number
               FROM mytable mi
               WHERE mi.created_at = (SELECT min(mii.created_at)
                                             FROM mytable mii)) difference,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM mytable mi) number_of_rows,
       ((SELECT mi.total_number
                FROM mytable mi
                WHERE mi.created_at = (SELECT max(mii.created_at)
                                              FROM mytable mii))
        -
        (SELECT mi.total_number
                FROM mytable mi
                WHERE mi.created_at = (SELECT min(mii.created_at)
                                              FROM mytable mii)))
       /
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM mytable mi) avg;
```

But you will get a problem if there is more than one row in `mytable` having the minimum (or maximum) value for `created_at`. To handle that case you need to define which one of the possible `total_number` values should be chosen then. The IDs don't look serial to me, so they cannot be used to solve such a conflict I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I assume "first" and "last" value are defined by the `created_at` column. Your approach can be extended to use both sub-query and combine them into a single one:

```
with fvalue as (
  -- get the first value and count the total number of rows
  select id, 
         created_at,
         total_number, 
         count(*) over () as number_of_rows
  from mytable
  order by created_at
  limit 1
), lvalue as (
  select id, 
         created_at,
         total_number
  from mytable
  order by created_at desc
  limit 1
)
select lv.total_number - fv.total_number as diff, 
       fv.number_of_rows, 
       (lv.total_number - fv.total_number) / fv.number_of_rows::decimal as avg
from fvalue fv
  cross join lvalue lv
```

The window function `count(*) over ()` counts all rows in the table and is evaluated *before* the `limit` clause.